# Encoding Script that you intend to document in body of HTML file

Tags: html, encode

I am attempting to document a JavaScript library and would like to place the function blocks from the script into the body, not to run but to view.

How do I encode that information such that the DOM treats this as text.

CDATA?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what doesn't work, thanks :)

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct or add a comment/answer with the method you have chosen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my concerns

```
 var encodeStr = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(nonEncodedStr)
               .Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
               .Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
               .Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a poorly worded question, from what I can gather; you want to display the source code, not run/render it. The best way would be to replace `>` and `<` with `&gt;` and `&lt;`

**Example**

```
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
document.write("blah");
}
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Renders:

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("blah");
}
</script>

Comment: Additional note - as a comment because it's not directly relevant - for large amounts I would do some kind of string replacement server side. For smaller jobs, open Notepad -> Find and Replace...

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you place it inside "pre" block.

Comment: I said "also". It means you still have to do what the previous answer asked you to.

Comment: I know, but I'm not the one who downvoted your answer - It would be nice to have it standalone though, since answers can change in position. I'll edit it in.